# Is a trap possible that abuses a vampire's invitation weakness?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead

Here's the idea I had:

Design two residences back to back such that there is a dining hall in the middle surrounded on all sides (through the use of second floors and basements). One person owns the front half and the other owns the back half and they both co-own the dining hall. Make this all officially legally binding via a written contract. Invite a vampire in your front house, then into the dining hall. Revoke your invitation from both your sole-owned private residence and the shared residence, and he is now trapped. He is not allowed to enter either private property and there is no other direction to go.

Similarly, make a permanent teleportation circle in the dining hall with the same setup. Invite him to accompany you with any teleportation method that can use the teleportation circle as the target and allows multiple targets. Revoke the invitation once he's in the hall

You might have to Anti-Magic-Field the dining hall in such a way that it just barely doesn't disrupt the teleportation circle, or else he could teleport away with something like *Dimension Door*

This does assume you can successfully persuade and deceive him in via roleplaying and good rolls.

Comment: Are you asking if *a* trap is possible, or if *this* trap is possible? I feel like those two questions need radically-different treatment.

Comment: I'm asking both. If this doesn't work, then also offer something that would or say why a vampire trap is explicitly impossible.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's not how the site works. Questions that are “here are my ideas, what are yours” are [explicitly off topic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because they are non-functional in the Q&A and voting system we have. Can you revise this to be one question that can have a factual answer, without any need to brainstorm or gather ideas? Thanks!

Comment: (Although, if gathering ideas is the *point* of this question, and asking the kind of question we do host here wouldn't help you, you may just actually want a chat room or discussion forum instead of a Stack. We've put together [a list of such sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) we recommend for those kinds of questions.)

Comment: As another issue if you should try to further develop this question, Is there even a mechanic for revoking an invitation?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson What if you sell the place?